# php path issue, solution needed

Tags: php

The following code works when I place this script in the root

```
if (file_exists("pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
```

but if I move my script to a folder /teacher/ it no longer works.

I thought make the path ~/pics/2012/blackhall primary/ would work but it does.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use / at the very beginning to indicate the root folder where your original php file was located

```
if (file_exists("/pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, 1 way is to use ../pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/ try this code. And sometimes special characters cause problem, remove them like space, %, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `file_exists` function check a file from the current folder or sub-folders .So if the teacher folder is not a sub-folder for  *Blackhall Primary* it won't work

[file_exists() - documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)